# How to configure databases in springboot interchangeably

Tags: database, oracle, spring-boot, azure-sql-database, kubernetes-helm

I need to enable code to interchangeably uses a different database by changing configuration. I have Oracle SQL and Azure SQL Server. By changing helm chart (or configuration), I would like to choose which database to use. Things I know are:

1. Datasource is configured in helm chart. I have a yaml file that declares driver, url, username and password for database.

```
   env:
      - name: datasource.project.driverClassName
        value: 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver'
      - name: datasource.project.url
        value: 'url'
      - name: datasource.project.username 
        value: 'username'
      - name: datasource.project.password
        value: 'password'
```

2. In my project, I create bean for database:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class ProjectDataSourceConfig {

    public static final String DB_TX_MANAGER = "";

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("datasource.project")
    public DataSourceProperties projectDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource projectDataSource() {
        return projectDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(ComboPooledDataSource.class).build();
    }

   
    @Bean
    public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate projectJdbcTemplate() {
        return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(projectDataSource());
    }

    @Bean(name = DB_TX_MANAGER)
    public DataSourceTransactionManager projectDbtransactionManager() {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(projectDataSource());
    }
}
```

My goal is: **to find a way to load either Oracle SQL OR Azure SQL Server by modifying configuration file.** I am not sure if just changing driverClassName, url, username and password is sufficient enough.

Answer (score 0):

I found this very easy. Since I don't use Hibernate, I can just simply change driver, url, username and password to Azure SQL's, then it works.